# Get index and columns based on conditional

Tags: python, pandas

Having a `DF` as the example below, how can i get list with the index and column name of the values that arent nan?

```
                  es  ms        hs
subdist_id                        
1                NaN NaN       NaN
2                NaN NaN       NaN
3          -0.218066 NaN -0.309002
4                NaN NaN       NaN
5                NaN NaN       NaN
6                NaN NaN       NaN
7                NaN NaN       NaN
9                NaN NaN       NaN
10               NaN NaN       NaN
11         -0.385217 NaN       NaN
```

so i can get a list `[[3,'es]', [3,'hs'], [11,'es']]`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use [`DataFrame.stack`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.stack.html) for remove NaNs with convert MultiIndex to list of tuples and then convert it to list of lists:

```
L = list(map(list, df.stack().index.tolist()))
print (L)
[[3, 'es'], [3, 'hs'], [11, 'es']]
```

Alternative:

```
L = [list(x) for x in df.stack().index.tolist()]
print (L)
[[3, 'es'], [3, 'hs'], [11, 'es']]
```

If need performance,get indices by condition by [`DataFrame.isna`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.isna.html) and [`numpy.where`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.where.html) and get values by zip with indexing for values of columns and index:

```
i,c = np.where(df.notna())
L = list(map(list, zip(df.index[i],df.columns[c])))
print (L)
[[3, 'es'], [3, 'hs'], [11, 'es']]
```

---

```
i,c = np.where(df.notna())
L = [list(x) for x in zip(df.index[i],df.columns[c])]
```